# Can't connect to Kubernetes API from any other host

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci

I installed a Kubernetes cluster (1 master + 1 node) on two Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS machines.

From the master, I can easily access the API, for example using `curl -v -k https://<IP>:6443/api`

From any other host I just get a timeout error. Scanning the ports, port 6443 looks closed.

The thing is, I need to configure GitLab CI using Kubernetes integration. I give it:

- API URL: `https://<IP>:6443/api`
- Token I got from Kubernetes
- Certificate I got from Kubernetes

I get the following when trying to configure my cluster for uploading containers:

```
$ kubectl config set-cluster my-cluster --server="$KUBE_URL" --certificate-authority="$KUBE_CA_PEM_FILE"
Cluster "my-cluster" set.
$ kubectl config set-credentials admin --token="$KUBE_TOKEN"
User "admin" set.
$ kubectl config set-context default-context --cluster=my-cluster --user=admin
Context "default-context" set.
$ kubectl config use-context default-context
Switched to context "default-context".
$ kubectl get cs
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp <IP>:6443: i/o timeout
```

What am I doing wrong? Hint: I am completely new to Kubernetes but I still want to connect a private GitLab, a private Docker registry and a private Kubernetes cluster. Can't find any single online resource covering this...

**Complementary information**:

I could connect a node to this master by `kubeadm join --token TOKEN <IP>:6443 --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash HASH` without any problem.

`netstat -nplt` gives:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10248         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1242/kubelet
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10249         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2225/kube-proxy
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10251         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1978/kube-scheduler
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1887/etcd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10252         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1926/kube-controlle
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2380          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1887/etcd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1289/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::10250                :::*                    LISTEN      1242/kubelet
tcp6       0      0 :::6443                 :::*                    LISTEN      1904/kube-apiserver
tcp6       0      0 :::10255                :::*                    LISTEN      1242/kubelet
tcp6       0      0 :::10256                :::*                    LISTEN      2225/kube-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1289/sshd
```

Comment: Where do you find this:  --certificate-authority="$KUBE_CA_PEM_FILE"

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a timeout error, it is highly likely that you have a firewall blocking the traffic. I advise to check your Cloud Provider firewall (for example, AWS Security groups) and see if the port is accessible.

If that is not the option, I advise you to execute the following command in your master:

```
sudo netstat -nplt
```

And check if kube-apiserver is listening in `127.0.0.1:6443` or `0.0.0.0:6443`. In case of the former, then check the kube-apiserver systemd service for changing the API listening address.

Comment: The only line I get for port 6443 is: ``tcp6       0      0 :::6443                 :::*                    LISTEN      -``

Comment: Why doesn't it listen to IPv4?

Comment: How did you install the cluster?

Comment: 1/ kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16, 2/ sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1, 3/ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/v0.9.0/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml 4/ kubeadm join --token TOKEN <masterIP>:6443 --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash <HASH>

Comment: This is weird, can you check that the packets arrive with tcpdump?

Comment: Packets coming every second from 10.244.0.4:55488, but nothing from the host which makes the kubectl query.

Answer (score 0):

As you are in a private network cluster I recommend you to check the firewall and also the authorized master networks [1](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/authorized-networks). You may test the connectivity and also ensure node has the port opened (`sudo ufw allow 6443` to open port in Ubuntu OS firewall). Give a look at this private cluster architecture diagram [2](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/private-cluster-concept#architecture).

There's can also `kubectl config view` to get  information about the client-server status, the k8s context can be updated with `kubectl config use-context XXX` [3](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/).

Related [4](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1224#issuecomment-316411907).